# MouseOver-Event on SVG-Path doesn't fire properly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, events, firefox

Edit: It's not only a ExtJs-issue; it doesn't work on pure SVGs with pure Javascript either.

I have an Ext.draw.Sprite that is defined like

```
Ext.create('Ext.draw.Sprite', {
        type           : 'path',
        stroke         : 'lightgrey',
        'stroke-width' : 8,
        path           : path,
        listeners      : {
            mouseover : Handler.clickZoneMouseOver,
            mouseout  : Handler.clickZoneMouseOut,
            click     : Handler.clickZoneClick,
            mousedown : Handler.clickZoneMouseDown,
            mouseup   : Handler.clickZoneMouseUp
        }
    });
```

The Handler simply says

```
console.log('mouseover')
```

On Google Chrome it works perfect and without any problems. Unfortunately, on Firefox the mouseover- and the mouseout-Events are only fired "sometimes". So when I perform 10 mouseovers and mouseouts, the event is fired like once or twice.

I wanted to create a jsfiddle that shows the problem, but there it works without any problems... http://jsfiddle.net/P6Ny3/
So it may be a Problem with the ExtJS-Listener classes...

Does someboy know, what may be the problem in this case?

Thank you for your help!

EDIT:
I managed to create a jsfiddle, that shows exactly my problem!
http://jsfiddle.net/8r327/2/
There is - also in pure javascript - a strange behaviour on firing the events!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are hitting the following FF bug:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=676001

It's been reported 2 years ago, has multiple duplicates, but as of now have not been fixed yet.  :(

Comment: Yes, this seems to be exactly my problem...
It looks like there is no workaround, so i have to live with these difficulties... unfortunately.
But thank you for your answer. At least I know now, where this problem comes from...